# network manager not working

Tags: network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 server. Recently, I installed Ubuntu desktop for it; before that it had automatically gained an IP address through DHCP. After installing Ubuntu desktop, I have provided an IP address as static but it is not obtaining that IP address. Instead, it is showing the DHCP address. When I check connection information, it is showing me the error message, "Error displaying connection information, no valid active connection found." I tried with `ifconfig` command but it shows the IP address as gained by DHCP but not the static one which I gave so I can browse the internet. I need to provide a static IP address. I have uploaded the error image. Please help me.[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How and where did you set up the static IP address? In Network Manager?

Comment: I have attached two more images on that how i have added an ip address and its showing it has been never used.

Comment: Are you quite sure the gateway is 192.168.1.50? Usually, the router address is xx.1 or xx.254. What is the gateway address in other devices on the same network?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your interface configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, remove it. NetworkManager won't manage static ip's configured there.

Then restart network-manager.

Answer (score 1):

**Check your network configuration files are same or not. These files are default configuration of Ubuntu.**

Open Terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now edit the file:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
inface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now save that file.

After this step you have to open another file via terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

After doing this editing job. Run this final command :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And then restart your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If when using static IP addresses you are getting a problem with name resolution, you will have to specifiy specific dns (domain name servers) in order to translate URLs to IP addresses.

`sudo ifconfig <interface> down`

`sudo dhclient -r <interface>`

`sudo ifconfig <interface> 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

`sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1`

`sudo iwconfig <interface> essid "ESSID_IN_QUOTES"`

`sudo iwconfig <interface> mode Managed`

Unfortunately there is not an easy way to configure this from the command line. This requires that you edit the /etc/resolv.conf file and manually enter the domain name server(s) you want to use. In many cases users can specifiy their router, their internet service providers dns servers, or use opendns (or use all three). Up to three nameservers can be specified.

`sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`

and add the nameservers you want to use, one to a line, in the following format.

`nameserver <nameserver>`

using this technique with static IP addresses, network manager has to be uninstalled because it keeps trying to reset the connection. In order to uninstall network manager

`sudo aptitude uninstall network-manager-gnome`

Best help I could find. Information taken from here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188